Disjunctive normal form of the negation of a disjunctive normal form.
Let $\mathsf{B}$ be a Boolean algebra with carrier set $B$ and Boolean operations $\vee,\wedge,(-)'$ and constants $0,1$. Let $a,b,c,d\in B$. Let us consider the Boolean function $p_{a,b,c,d}\colon B^2\to B$ given by $p_{a,b,c,d}(x,y):=(a\wedge x\wedge y)\vee (b\wedge x\wedge y')\vee (c\wedge x'\wedge y)\vee (d\wedge x'\wedge y')$.
I have read somewhere that the complement (aka negation) $p_{a,b,c,d}(x,y)'$ of $p_{a,b,c,d}(x,y)$ is equal to $(a'\wedge x\wedge y)\vee (b'\wedge x\wedge y')\vee (c'\wedge x'\wedge y)\vee (d'\wedge x'\wedge y')$.
Does anyone know of a conceptual way of obtaining the negation of $p_{a,b,c,d}(x,y)$ in the form given above, without writing the truth table (with its 64 lines)? (I know I'm lazy.)

I would draw a little picture with the universe being the square $[-1,1]\times [-1,1]$ split into the four little squares $x\cap y,x'\cap y,\dots$ in the obvious way; and then let $a$ be the quarter circle of radius $1$ inside $x\cap y$ etc. It's clear now what happens when you take the complement.
